# Sorting data files in Python

Tags: python, sorting, date

I have a lot of files numbered by the day of the year they were created. For example:

- rate_2017_04.txt
- rate_2017_09.txt
- rate_2017_45.txt
- rate_2017_99.txt
- rate_2017_146.txt
- rate_2017_267.txt

Where the last number indicates the day of the year. I'm trying to sort those files by using

```
rate_file_list = sorted(glob.glob('rate_201*.txt'))
```

But by doing that I'm obtaining something like:

- rate_2017_04.txt
- rate_2017_09.txt
- rate_2017_146.txt
- rate_2017_267.txt
- rate_2017_45.txt
- rate_2017_99.txt

Is there any way to set `sorted()` to solve this?

Comment: this can be done with one single line in linux command-line. Fast and simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sorted) accepts the `key` argument, which is a function that is used to extract a comparison key from each element of the iterable. You could use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) for that:

```
from datetime import datetime

def keyfunc(value):
    return datetime.strptime(value, "rate_%Y_%j.txt")  

rate_file_list = sorted(glob.glob('rate_201*.txt'), key=keyfunc)
```

Now the values will compare as dates, which is what you want.